# Python Regex matching for preposition - Word Boundary issue

Tags: python, regex

From the strings like this: 
"Laughing Eyes Photo in Lawton, Ok" ,I want to extract 
"Laughing Eyes Photo". I wrote the following code.

```
PREPOSITIONS = ["at","in"]
matches = re.search(r"^([\w&,.\'\s]+)" + r"(\b{}\b)".
                      format('|'.join(PREPOSITIONS)), title, re.I)
  if matches:
    return matches.group(1).strip().title()
```

It works well for the above. But for the following example, it fails.
'Mountain Star Salon Services'. There is no preposition "in" here, but still it catches "in" present in the word "Mountain" despite giving a word boundary /b. 
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string-joining results in something like `(\bat|in\b)`.  This means either `\bat` or `in\b` --- that is, the word boundaries are only applied at the beginning of the first alternate and the end of the last, not on each one.

Try `r"\b({})\b"` instead.